# My Textfield UITableViewCell and my textfieldShouldReturn are not seeing eye to eye

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, nscell

After selecting a `cell` and writing something in it, I would like to hit the return/next button on the keyboard and simply move to the next `cell`, that's what I am trying to achieve. But after placing a `breakpoint` on my method `textfieldShouldReturn`, I find that it does not get visited, even though I pressed on the return/next key. Can someone explain why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `cell`. It will only call when you have `UITextField` in the `cell` and also set `delegate` to `self`.

```
UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CellFrame];
text.tag=indexPath.row;
txt.delegate=self;
```

`[cell.contentView addSubview:txt];`

then it will definitely call `textFieldShouldReturn` method. on return click

Comment: I have similar, I tried adding my code as answer but I have to wait 8hours. I have seen several post telling other people with similar issues about files owner and delegate, but how can I make something that is programmatically part of files owner? If that is even the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface WordListTableController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}

@end
```

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
FirstField.delegate = self;
[FirstField setTag:indexPath.row];
FirstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
[cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
[FirstField release];


return cell;
}


// Handle any actions, after the return/next/done button is pressed
- (BOOL)textfieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textfield 
{
[textfield resignFirstResponder];

return NO;
}
```